# PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar in JDBC Spring

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have an update method to update the content of a table based on a specific field and I am getting following exception.

Code is :

```
public void updateTaxoActive(String oldDesc, String description) {
    Logger.getLogger(TypeCategoryJDBCTemplate.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "old taxonomy code is {0} new description is {1}", new Object[]{oldDesc, description});
    String sql = "update product.typecategory set taxonomydescription = ? where taxonomydescription = ?";
    jdbcTemplateObject.update(sql, new Object[]{description,oldDesc},new TypeCategoryMapper());
}
```

Exception is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [update product.typecategory set taxonomydescription = ? where taxonomydescription = ?]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][1091][10824][4.13.127] Invalid data conversion: Parameter instance [Ljava.lang.Object;@1dc421 is invalid for the requested conversion. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:818)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:874)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:882)
    at com.ibm.quest.model.typecategory.TypeCategoryJDBCTemplate.updateTaxoActive(TypeCategoryJDBCTemplate.java:59)
    at com.ibm.quest.taxonomyupdate.ui.ApplicationWindow.updateButtonActionPerformed(ApplicationWindow.java:255)
    at com.ibm.quest.taxonomyupdate.ui.ApplicationWindow.access$800(ApplicationWindow.java:16)
    at com.ibm.quest.taxonomyupdate.ui.ApplicationWindow$10.actionPerformed(ApplicationWindow.java:218)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][1091][10824][4.13.127] Invalid data conversion: Parameter instance [Ljava.lang.Object;@1dc421 is invalid for the requested conversion. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:677)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:60)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:103)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.c(oo.java:2584)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.oo.setObject(oo.java:2363)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:365)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:217)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:145)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:46)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:822)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:818)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:589)
    ... 43 more
```

Comment: 42815 in sql means "The replacement value for '<value>' is invalid." check http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.5/ref/rrefexcept71493.html check if there is a any mismatch between the datatypes and the data you are passing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you doing with TypeCategoryMapper ?

Remove `,new TypeCategoryMapper()`